# Python Tkinter text insert from another module

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-text

I'm using python for my little project and for fun
I made my program one single file and it's kinda large and messy right now
so I decide try to devide several files and import it.
It's ok to work but the problem is I have no idea how to use text.insert func

gui_test.py

```
from tkinter import *
import threading
from test import test_fun


def t_test():
    t0 = threading.Thread(target=test_fun)
    t0.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = Tk()
    root.title(f"test_gui")
    root.geometry("355x280")

    txt = Text(root, width=50, height=10, wrap=WORD)  # log
    txt.place(x=0, y=20)
    txt.config(state=NORMAL)

    btn1 = Button(root, text="test_button", command=t_test)
    btn1.place(x=5, y=160)

    root.mainloop()
```

test.py

```
import time

def test_fun():
    sec = 0
    while True:
        txt.insert(END, f"{sec}\n")
        sec += 1
        time.sleep(1)
```

How can I send some text and show on gui_test.py?

Looking for easiest way

Solved

gui_test.py

```
from tkinter import *
import threading
from test import test_fun

def t_test():
    t0 = threading.Thread(target=test_fun, args=(root,), daemon=False)
    t0.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = Tk()
    root.title(f"test_gui")
    root.geometry("355x280")

    root.txt = Text(root, width=50, height=10, wrap=WORD)  # log
    root.txt.place(x=0, y=20)
    root.txt.config(state=NORMAL)

    btn1 = Button(root, text="test_button", command=t_test)
    btn1.place(x=5, y=160)

    root.mainloop()
```

test.py

```
import time
from tkinter import *


def test_fun(widget):
    sec = 0
    while True:
        widget.txt.insert(END, f"{sec}\n")
        widget.txt.update()
        widget.txt.see(END)
        sec += 1
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to run `test_fun` in a separate thread / have a while loop inside `test_fun`? If you're looking for an easy way to update something periodically, check out tkinter's `after` method - no threading required!

Comment: In test.py, you can't do this txt.insert(END, f"{sec}\n"). There are no widget(s). But you can do this print(f"{sec}\n")

Comment: You can pass `txt` as an argument of `test_fun()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the Tk() object to the function if you want the function to be able to change anything in it:

```
def test_fun(widget):
    sec = 0
    while True:
        widget.txt.insert(END, f"{sec}\n")
        widget.txt.update()
        sec += 1
        time.sleep(1)
```

And then you need to make the Text box a part of the widget:

```
    root.txt = Text(root, width=50, height=10, wrap=WORD)  # log
    root.txt.place(x=0, y=20)
    root.txt.config(state=NORMAL)
```

Now, you can call the function by writing `test_fun(root)` and it will start filling the window.
(unfortunately, I'm not familiar with threading. But a lambda-function passing root should be feasible)